# How to detect overlapping communities in python

Tags: python, networkx

I have a network data set generated by python and run community analysis on that using the package python-louvain(community). You can find the graph below.[image]

So you can see each node belongs to one community which is mark by different colors. Now, I want to add an additional field containing information of each nodes to the network data. For instance, person A can have three communities namely 1,2,and 3, and the algorithm determines community 1 is the primary community and assign person A to community 1. However, instead of finding out the most significant community, I would like to just list out all the potential communities and add that as an attribute to each node. So in this case, person A will have community 1,2,and 3.

Comment: Looks like you want to add node attributes. What's the problem?

Comment: I am not sure how do you find out all communities for each node.

Comment: If you use module `community`, each node belongs exactly to one community. What do you mean by "all"?

Comment: The idea is that one node can be connected to multiple communities and what the algorithm does is to find the partition of the graph nodes which maximizes the modularity. So instead of maximizing the modularity, I just want all partitions/communities. You can find the function here:https://python-louvain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: Are you able to share sample data, with the persons belonging to multiple communities and one primary community? That way those helping can try things out

Comment: Yes, try this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ezk1LjGrqT1b49TNlSYDawx28oLe0bus7WFHSjfYD14/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The package you mentioned does not have any algorithm to detect multiple communities. Do you have any algorithm implemented ?

Comment: No. Any idea which package has the algorithm to detect multiple communities?